# Add Disqus like commenting option for android app

Tags: android

I am new to android development. Is there any way to add commenting option for android app. I googled but not get required answer. I have no idea to do it. Any api for it? My app is related to news. In news web site users can post comment under every news. web site use disqus. I want to use such commenting option for app.

Comment: this time you asked it properly

Comment: Check out their API: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1104798-using-the-api